# Inaccessible host : This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to access s3 from lambda function. S3 bucket and Lambda are in the same region. But I am getting same error:

> Inaccessible host: 'zfund-data-storage-pre.dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the 'ap-south-1' region.

This is my code

```
var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME } });

AWS.config.update({
secretAccessKey     : process.env.SECRET_KEY,
accessKeyId         : process.env.API_KEY,
region:"ap-south-1",
s3BucketEndpoint:true,
endpoint:"https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
});
var params5 = {
  Key: 'filename'
}
var resp =  await s3Bucket.getObject(params5).promise();
```

This is the response I'm getting.

```json
{
    "status": "failed",
    "message": {
        "message": "Inaccessible host: `bucketname.dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `ap-south-1' region.",
        "code": "UnknownEndpoint",
        "region": "ap-south-1",
        "hostname": "bucketname-pre.dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
        "retryable": true,
        "originalError": {
            "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bucketname.dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
            "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
            "code": "NetworkingError",
            "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
            "hostname": "bucketname.dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
            "region": "ap-south-1",
            "retryable": true,
            "time": "2021-02-05T10:11:17.469Z"
        },
        "time": "2021-02-05T10:11:17.469Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to set the global endpoint for the API to `dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: if i dontset, still gets the same error.

Comment: `https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` is invalid endpoint for s3. Maybe it should be `https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: I have removed endpoint....but i am getting same error.

Comment: Can you try to remove both the `s3BucketEndpoint` and the `endpoint` configuration - I don't see why you need them here.

Comment: Yes, i have removed..both endpoint s..but i get the same error.

Comment: With the same Domain it's trying to access?

Comment: Yes..but the error is same....i have other lambdas also in same region...there is no problemm with that..but first time i amm getting this type of error.

Comment: Wait, this is a Lambda function and you're passing in the credentials via Environment Variables instead of using roles? o.O

Comment: @Herry you missed @marcin's point the endpoint you have in your post is for dynamodb `https://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` it should be s3 endpoint like `https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`. Endpoints in general are `endpoint: 'https://{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com'`  as per the documentation.